# Create a column where parent items are listed with their respective children under them

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have created 2 tables as an example.
Table1:

```
    Gender Table
    ID    | Gender
---------------------
0000-0000 | MALE
0000-0001 | FEMALE
```

Table2:

```
Table
ID |  PARENTID | NAME
----------------------
1  | 0000-0001 | Apple
2  | 0000-0000 | Bob
3  | 0000-0000 | Chris
4  | 0000-0000 | Dan
5  | 0000-0001 | Elsa
```

The PARENTID of table2 refers to the IDs of Table1.
From that we can see that Apple is Female and Bob is Male.

However, I need the output to look like this.

```
List
-----
MALE
Bob
Chris
Dan
FEMALE
Apple
Elsa
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: SQL returns sets, unordered sets, unless explicitly specified. SQL way is two column result (Name, Gender).

Comment: In other words, your solution is violating SQL to begin with. If you wish this to be dynamic, one solution would be: insert a dummy row that identifies all gender types (male and female are sexes). Use a grouping set (GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (<group A>), (<group B>), etc) where these results can return in those sets. You can provide some order, but this would require altering the SELECT statement. At least this method would use one complex query instead of multiple queries. :) but do you need the identifying label in the query results?

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL to combine the results:

```
select name
from
(1 as SortOrder, 'Male' as name
+
2, male names (apply WHERE clause)
+
3, 'Female'
+
4, female names(apply WHERE clause)
) Q
order by SortOrder
```

UPDATE (universal solution):

Assuming:

*you have ID in Gender table, and that ID is in desired order (otherwise you need to add some int column to specify the order)

*assuming Min ID in Name table is not negative

```
select Q.Name
from

(select g.GenderID as GenderSortOrder, -1 as NameSortOrder, GenderName as Name
from #gender g

union all

select g.GenderID, t.ID, t.Name
from #gender g
    inner join #name t on t.GenderID = g.GenderID) Q

order by Q.GenderSortOrder, Q.NameSortOrder
```

Comment: This doesn't seem dynamic though. What if the parents weren't genders and the number of parents could vary? This is quite hardcoded and I need it to work for all cases.

Comment: What change to you expect to see? More genders? Gender table is usually static, so my solution works for it. If you need general solution, then the query should be modified. Let me think...

Comment: Yes I need it to be general. I just created these 2 tables as an example to show what kind of output I want. Let's say I added a homosexual item to Table1, and some names of people who identify as homosexual in Table2. I would like it to have the desired output without rewriting the Query. Thank you for helping

Comment: Updated the script. Please mark the answer as answered if it is what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)='';
SELECT @sql += 'SELECT '+QUOTENAME(Gender, '''')
    +' List UNION ALL SELECT NAME FROM Table2 WHERE ParentId='+QUOTENAME(ID, '''')
    +char(13)+char(10)+'UNION ALL'+char(13)+char(10)
FROM Table1

SET @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql)-13)

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `UNION ALL`, add an extra column t to tell which table is selected.
Order the result:

```
select list
from
(
  select ID, 1 as t, Gender as list
  from table1
  union all
  select PARENTID, 2 as t, NAME
  from table2
)
order by id, t, list
```